# Facebook like button within iFRAME

Tags: facebook

I wonder if someone may be able to help me with a simple question, its been a while since I created or used facebook like button, but it appears I need to include an app ID now with the iframe code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FXYZ&amp;width&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button&amp;show_faces=false&amp;appId=0000000" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

A lot has changed since I did this so my question is do I need to get the app approved for the above.

I created my APP with the basic settings and then just copied and pasted the ap ID into the code.

Also is there anything else I need to change / add in the app? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the like button not working? Does it appear? Are there an JS errors?

Comment: @lix, it appears to be working and only error is: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.facebook.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.facebook.com').

Comment: Is it just me - or did you give `facebook.com` as the URL for the like plugin? I don't think that will work - try giving an actual URL that you want to use...

Comment: @Lix, i changed the URL and the AP ID, they are actual pages and APP IDS in my code, i just changed for privacy reasons thats all, thanks odd